# If "struct" and "class" are same thing then why only "class" is used in template<class T> not the "struct"?

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct

```
template<class T>
struct E{};     //// no error


template<struct T>
struct F{};    ////error
```

> error: a non-type template parameter cannot have type 'struct T'
> template

If `class` and `struct` are the same things except the by-default `private` and `public` access specifiers, then why doesn't this work ?

Comment: For template parameters, you can use `class` or `typename`.  Not `class` or `struct`.  C++ often has keywords that are used differently in different contexts.  The use-case is one such different context.

Comment: You're taking that statement out of context. The proper context is when they're used for class definitions.

Comment: "Because the Standard Says So"(tm)

Comment: My usual statement on the difference is "The only difference you are ever likely to see is `class` defaults to `private` access and `struct` defaults to `public` access." I've seen a few language lawyer battles over a couple edge cases in C++11 that, I think, only compiler writers and those solving very interesting problems care about. And the wording may have been cleaned up in subsequent revisions. I'm not writing a compiler or solving very interesting problems, so I've never compared the wording they fought over.

Comment: Did anybody tell LightningRacesInOrbit? He always insists there are only classes in C++.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I believe one of the combatants WAS Lightning.

Comment: They are not the same thing in any context.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that `struct` and `class` are *distinct keywords*. I.e., they are not mere aliases of each other at a lexical level, but can be used differently by the language in different places. So the fact that they behave similarly in one context does not mean you can use them interchangeably in another context.

As you state, they are similar when defining a class, but **that is all**. Defining a type template parameter is a completely different thing than defining a class, and it has its own syntax. That syntax is unrelated to the syntax for defining a class, and the fact that the keyword `class` is used in both can be considered a mere coincidence from a syntactic standpoint (a helpful coincidence, but still). And that syntax dictates that `class` (or `typename`) must be used when defining a type template parameter.

Comment: Today I learned: another difference between `struct` and `class` for defining a class is that the Microsoft ABI mangles them differently.

Comment: @Eljay Interesting: Potentially for C/C++ interop, i.e. they are default "extern C"? Would make using the same headers on both sides easier.

Comment: It would be interesting to know for sure what the reason is. It seems bizarre to me that the ABI would depend on whether one keyword or another is used when they accomplish the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can write `template<struct T>`, but first please define a literal type `T`, then `template<struct T>` will be identical to `template<T>` and specify non-type template parameter of type `T`.

For example, the following program is valid in C++20:

```
class T {};

template <class T>
struct E {};

template <struct T>
struct F {};

int main() {
  [[maybe_unused]] E<T> a;
  [[maybe_unused]] F<T{}> b;
}
```

and accepted by all compilers, online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/77qeq48d6

Only Clang warns us here:

```
warning: struct 'T' was previously declared as a class; this is valid, but may result in linker errors under the Microsoft C++ ABI [-Wmismatched-tags]
```

Comment: Couple notes: 1) the warning is easily avoided by replacing `class T {};` with the equivalent `struct T {};`.  2) Just to call this out for anyone skimming this answer (I missed it at first), we can only write `template<struct T>` because `struct T` is an unnamed _non-type template parameter_ of type `T`. It is not at all like using `class T` which would be a _type template parameter_ named `T`, as we've been accustomed to for a long time now. Check out [Elaborated type specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier) if this use of `struct` is new to you :)